# zabbix jboss monitored by zabbix

Tags: jboss, zabbix, jmx

I try monitor JBoss by zabbix. I create Template and HOST. In Host I use JMX Interfaces. But when I enable this host I see this error:

"java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.Connect.

Please give me some advice, how I can fix it?.

Regards
Mick

Comment: Check out ngDesk for managing tickets and server issues https://www.ngdesk.com

Comment: i create native JMX discovery template. [https://share.zabbix.com/official-templates/wildfly-eap-jboss-discovery](https://share.zabbix.com/official-templates/wildfly-eap-jboss-discovery)

Answer (score 1):

I got Zabbix to monitor JBoss using the following link.

http://skajla.blogspot.com/2010/07/jboss-monitoring-using-zabbix.html

It basically requires you to enable JMX on your server. Then run his .jar file server-side through UserParameters.

```
UserParameter=Daemon_Threads,java -jar /opt/skajla-JMXClient.jar 127.0.0.1 9999 admin jmxpass java.lang:type=Threading DaemonThreadCount
```

Just make sure your Zabbix Agent has permissions to run the .jar file.

If it returns some garbage values, you may need to change some of JMX parameters, which I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

"Enterprise Application servers" usually use JMX for internal communication and even some CLI tools connect to JMX to send commands to application server. In that case JMX is configured, to only communicate with that tools for security reasons... accept only localhost connections and specific certificates generated during install. Investigate your JBoss JMX settings and its ACL settings. If you are satisfied with just JVM monitoring, you can find inspiration here: [JVM SNMP monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/404479/how-can-i-monitor-memory-usage-for-a-windows-based-jvm-and-trigger-an-alert-if-i/407951#407951) This way of monitoring could live independently of other settings.

Comment: Ok I resolve this JBoss EAP 5 supports JMX monitoring using RMI, where JBoss EAP 6 does not. EAP 6 uses “remoting-jmx” instead of “rmi”. This is a problem because the Zabbix Java Gateway only supports RMI for the JMX interface, preventing us from monitoring JBoss EAP 6 using JMX monitoring. Step to fix it:

1.Modify source code of the Zabbix Java Gateway to enable both RMI and remoting-jmx
2.Add the required libraries to the Zabbix Java Gateway